# Multiple Buttons In Fragment Class Issue?

Tags: android, button, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am Having an Issue Succesfully opening new activities
from these multiple buttons. Im new to coding though. can someone help
me with this issues..

I used fragments and I cannot to get to work please help. 
Here is my code so far.
Thank you

```
     public class CreditFragment1 extends Fragment {
     private static final View View = null;
         Button balance;
         Button recharge;
         Button share;
         Button buy;
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.credit_frag1_layout,
                container, false);

    // at the next line below i get "Unreachable code"
     balance =  (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.balance_bt);
     recharge =  (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.recharge_bt);
     share =  (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.share_bt);
     buy =  (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.buy_bt);


     OnClickListener balanceListener = new OnClickListener() {            
         public void onClick(View view) {
             setContentView(R.layout.balance_layout);
             Intent BalanceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),BalanceActivity.class);
             startActivity(BalanceIntent);
            }
        private void setContentView(int balanceLayout) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
     };

     OnClickListener rechargeListener = new OnClickListener() {            
         public void onClick(View view) {
             setContentView(R.layout.recharge_layout);
             Intent BalanceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),RechargeActivity.class);
             startActivity(BalanceIntent);
            }
        private void setContentView(int rechargeLayout) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
     };
     OnClickListener shareListener = new OnClickListener() {            
         public void onClick(View view) {
             setContentView(R.layout.share_layout);
             Intent BalanceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),ShareActivity.class);
             startActivity(BalanceIntent);
            }
        private void setContentView(int shareLayout) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
     };

     OnClickListener buyListener = new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
             setContentView(R.layout.buy_layout);
             Intent BalanceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),BuyActivity.class);
             startActivity(BalanceIntent);
            }
        private void setContentView(int buyLayout) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
     };
            balance.setOnClickListener(balanceListener);
            recharge.setOnClickListener(rechargeListener);
            share.setOnClickListener(shareListener);
            buy.setOnClickListener(buyListener);     
            return View;
     }
}
```

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: The issue facing that i cannot figure out hw to open the activities and layouts of those respective buttons.. nothing i try is working..

Answer (score 1):

Change `onCreateView` to

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.credit_frag1_layout,container, false);
    balance =  (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.balance_bt);
    balance.setOnClickListener(this);
    // similarly initialize other buttons
    return view;
 }
```

Also your class can implement `OnClickListener`

```
  public class CreditFragment1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
```

In onCreateView

```
 balance.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then override `onClick`.

```
@Override
public void onClikc(View v)
{
        switch(v.getId())
        {
          case R.id.balance_bt :
           // balance button clicked
          break; 
          case R.id.recharge_bt
          // recharge button clicked :
          break;   
          // similarly for other buttons
        }
 }
```

Also i am not sure what you are trying to do with `setContentView(R.layout.balance_layout);` in OnClickListener. Remove setContentView(R.layout.balance_layout);

If you need to navigate to a different Activity use `startActivtiy(intent)`

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you are trying to do?

For one thing, the method `setContentView(int shareLayout)` inside the `onClickListener` won't do anything for you. Specially if you leave it empty.

What I think you should do from what I understood is start the desired activity like so:

```
OnClickListener shareListener = new OnClickListener() {            
     public void onClick(View view) {
         Intent BalanceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),ShareActivity.class);
         startActivity(BalanceIntent);
        }
};
```

Then, inside the `onCreate()` of your `ShareActivity` class, put:

```
setContentView(R.layout.share_layout);
```

And remove all the `setContentView` from each of your `onClickListener()` events.

See the [Starting another activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) tutorial for details.

Hope it helps.