# Buttons not working in fragment

Tags: android, button, android-activity, onclick, fragment

I'm implementing two buttons in a fragment which on getting clicked will transfer to two different activities. However on clicking, nothing happens. The app does not force close nor the debugger shows any exception. Using Log.d I found that onClick is not getting called.
I had referred this post for implementing however it didn't work [Multiple Buttons In Fragment Class Issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302089/multiple-buttons-in-fragment-class-issue)

Here is my code

**TheOtherFragment.java**

```
package com.tct.level4;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TheOtherFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    Context context;
    private Button sound;
    private Button vib;
    View v;

    public TheOtherFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_the_other, container, false);
        context = container.getContext();
        sound = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.sound);
        vib = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.vibration);
        Log.d("onactivity", "called");
        sound.setOnClickListener(this);
        vib.setOnClickListener(this);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_the_other, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View va) {
        switch (va.getId()) {
            case R.id.vibration: 
                Log.d("vib","1");
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Vib.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.d("vib","2");
                break;

            case R.id.sound: 
                Log.d("sound","1");
                Intent inten = new Intent(context, Ring.class);
                startActivity(inten);
                Log.d("sound","2");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to return `v` instead of   `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_the_other, container, false);`, `inflater.inflate` returns a new object, and on it you haven't register the `onClickListener`